# Extract REMOTE_ADDR using mod_perl

Tags: perl, mod-perl

Please help how to extract REMOTE_ADDR value using mod_perl.

I have following perl script:

```perl
use Apache2::RequestUtil;
use Apache2::RequestRec;

$| = 1;
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

my $r = Apache2::RequestUtil->request;
print $r->as_string();
```

the result of script:

```
GET /tmp/recheaders.pl HTTP/1.0
X-Scheme: http
REMOTE_ADDR: 81.204.25.44
Host: dom.net
X-Real-IP: 81.204.25.44
X-Forwarded-for: 81.204.25.44
Connection: close
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: SESSION_ID=963bd96302cd70047c9f017640c7cbb8;
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.0 (null)
```

How can I extract only `REMOTE_ADDR: 81.204.25.44` ? What API method and how should I use?

**SOLUTION**

I found more elegant solution, to fetch just REMOTE_ADDR using `headers_in`:

```perl
use Apache2::Request;

my $r = shift;
my $req = Apache2::Request->new($r);
my $remip = $req->headers_in->{REMOTE_ADDR};

print $remip;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `%ENV`

```
print $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR};
```

Alternatively there is [`Apache2::Connection->remote_addr()`](https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Connection.html#C_remote_addr_)

```
use Apache2::Connection ();
use Apache2::RequestRec ();

my $c = $r->connection;

# this connection's local and remote socket addresses
my $local_sa  = $c->local_addr();
my $remote_sa = $c->remote_addr();
```

Comment: thanks, `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR};` works, but it shows different IP, my server IP instead of what shown by `$r->as_string();`, do you know the difference?

Comment: additionally, `my $c = $r->connection;`   $r variable is not defined, and it produces error.